# How to put condition on table row color by the table data?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, html-table

I am creating a table from two arrays using ngFor

```
    <tr *ngFor="let e of lis1; let k=index">
        <td>{{e}}  </td>
        <td>{{lis2[k]}}</td>
    
    </tr>
```

and the table created is something like this

```
Name  Age
a     15
b     20
c     25
```

I want to change the color of the row which has an age greater than 20.
How to put this condition??
I am using angular typescript.

in lis1 I have an array of names(a,b,c)
andin lis2 I have an array of age(15,20,25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways you can add styles to your element conditionally, `ngStyle`, `ngClass`, directly with attributes, etc.

I'll show You how to add styles using `ngClass`. You can simply check if the age is greater than 20 in `[ngClass]` to apply the class otherwise not.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let e of lis1; let k=index" [ngClass]="{'background-red': lis2[k] > 20}">
     <td>{{e}}  </td>
     <td>{{lis2[k]}}</td>  
</tr>
```

In your `CSS` component simple add the class

```
.background-red{
     background-color: red;
}
```